# Need help redirect 301 htaccess (i cannot find in all topic)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I rewrite url by .htaccess
I want rewrite URL:

```
abc.com/index.php?mod=products&cat=mu&pid=0&cid=26<br/>
```

to

```
abc.com/san-pham/mu-0-26.html
```

I using follow code

```
RewriteRule ^san-pham/(\.*)-(\.*)-(\.*)\.html$ index.php?mod=products&cat=$1&pid=$2&cid=$3 [R=301,L]
```

When click to URL `abc.com/san-pham/mu-0-26.html`, which redirected 301 to `abc.com/index.php?mod=products&cat=mu&pid=0&cid=26`

But I want `abc.com/index.php?mod=products&cat=mu&pid=0&cid=26` redirect 301 to `abc.com/san-pham/mu-0-26.html`

Anybody help me?
Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `R=301` in the rule that you have. You want that to internally rewrite and not externally redirect. Then add this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php\?cat=([^&]+)&pid=([^&]+)&cid=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /san-pham/%1-%2-%3.html? [L,R=301]
```